# Angular2 Routing - Child template not dispalying

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

I am trying to learn angular 2 routing and I am stuck here I can't get the template of child component to display. I have the following two pages

**page1.ts**

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: "page1",
    template: `page 1 goes here.`
})
export class Page1Cmp{}
```

**page2.ts**

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {RouterLink,RouteConfig} from 'angular2/router';
import {ChildCmp} from './child';

@Component({
    selector: "page2",
    template: `Hello its page 2
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>`
})
@RouteConfig([
    {path: "/", component: ChildCmp, name: "Child", useAsDefault: true}
  ])
export class Page2Cmp{}
```

Here is the child component that page2.ts is trying to route

**child.ts**

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: "child",
    template: `child content goes here.`
})
export class ChildCmp{}
```

This child component is not being displayed on page2
Here is the root component

**app.ts**

```
import {Component} from "angular2/core";
import {bootstrap} from "angular2/platform/browser";
import {ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, RouteConfig, ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from "angular2/router";
import {Page1Cmp} from './page1';
import {Page2Cmp} from './page2';

@Component({
    selector: "app",
    template: `<a [routerLink]="['Page1']">Page1</a> | <a [routerLink]="['Page2']">Page2</a>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    `,
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
@RouteConfig([
    {path: "/page1", name: "Page1", component: Page1Cmp, useAsDefault: true},
    {path: "/page2/...", name: "Page2", component: Page2Cmp}
])
class MyApp{}

bootstrap(MyApp, [
    ROUTER_PROVIDERS
]);
```

When I route to page2 I don't see the template of child.ts component. I re-produced the problem on [plunker here](http://embed.plnkr.co/49LURshDhLFNuvWUWbSX/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/MFF1DNLi4h19mbGLEok7?p=preview)**

```
import {RouterLink,RouteConfig,ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/router'; 

@Component({
    selector: "page2",

    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    //add this and it will start working as expected.

    template: `<br>Hello its page 2<br>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>`
})
```